# What does this dashed and curved line mean in pyruvate molecular graph?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: pyruvate]

Hi all, I came across this while researching a gene sequencing assignment and I cannot find out what the curved/dashed line means. Can anyone tell me please? Is it something to do with the negative symbol? Thanks

Comment: I’m guessing there is a duplicate lying around somewhere. If there is not, please leave open, answer accordingly and turn this into the dupe target.

Answer (score 7):

It actually *hybrid form* of the contributing **[resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance_(chemistry))** structures of the ion. The significance of the dashed line is that it shows *delocalisation of negative charge over the two oxygen atoms*.

[image]

Note that

- Neither of the above two forms represent the actual compound
- Actual compound is represented by the *resonance hybrid* :

[image]